# How to prove this set is countably infinite

Tags: set-theory

the question(translated form Hebrew):

let it be a function: $ f:N→N ,f(n)=n+1 $

prove:
{$g∈^NN:g∘f=Id_N$}$ = |N|.$

my first thought was: well simply prove
bijection. there is $$g_0(n) = n - 1,
g_1(n) = n -1 + (1 - 1), g_2(n) = n -1 + (2- 2)$$
and so on, but there are many ways to add a part to a function that doesn't do something so there isn't an obvious way to make a bijection that covers the whole set, I can prove that it is at least infinitely countable this way. The set is a subset of all the functions that are injections but that is $\aleph$ so not much help. I tried to find a rule that would help but haven't found any. I am also not sure if the function is the same for all inputs, does it count as one function? for example are g_1 and g_2 considered diffrent? if not then the set hold only one function and that doesn't make sense I think. thanks in advance.

Comment: What does this mean: {$g∈^N:g∘f=Id_N$}$ = |N|.$ ?

Comment: Hint:  note that there is no natural number $n$ such that $f(n)=1$.  (I am assuming that you don't have $0\in \mathbb N$.  If you do, then note that there is no natural number $n$ with $f(n)=0$).

Comment: Thank you, I missed the char there and now fixed it, it's a function from the natural numbers into the natural numbers to my best understanding.

Comment: Should also note that this isn't a "group", at least not in any obvious way.  Perhaps you just meant "set"?

Comment: Right! I am learning the words in English for this as we speak. fixing the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote the set whose cardinality we want to find by $G$. Notice that for $g:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$, we have $g\in G$ if and only if $g(n)=n-1$ for every $n\geq 1$. Notice that the value of $g$ at $0$ does not play a role for $g\circ f$ to be the identity. This means that every $g\in G$ is uniquely determined by its value $g(0)\in\mathbb N$. In other words, there is a bijection
$$G\ni g\mapsto g(0)\in\mathbb N,$$
hence the result.

You might want to explicitly check injectivity and surjectivity of my suggested map.

Comment: oh, that's right!  But just to make sure, if two functions are doing the exact same thing for every input for example g_1 and g_2 I gave, and the internals of them are different, are they considered the same function?

Comment: @ItaySegev Yes, they are then twice the same function: $g_1=g_2$. Just because the formula for $g_1$ looks different than the formula for $g_2$, we still have $g_1(n)=g_2(n)$ for every $n\geq 0$.